# Xamarin UITest, Possible to use AppResource functionality in tests?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I'd like to check the text of a label in one of my tests (in this case the text will be "pending", "verified" etc), however our app is localised and uses AppResources, so the text will be different in other languages.

So I don't want to hard code the string to look for say "pending".

Just wondering if it's possible to include (some kind of link to the files) the resx files in the main project.

I'm also going to need someway of using the correct language / resx file.

Comment: Are you looking to use RESX files in your UITest?

Comment: Try backdoors in UITest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/features/backdoors. You can find your demanded string in native method and call it from UITest

Comment: @BrandonMinnick sorry, I don't know how I missed your reply, also noticed your wonderful UI Testing examples yesterday... In answer to your question, Yes... do you have any ideas ?

Comment: I suppose specifically, I want to be able to get a constant to use in my UI Test project, rather than use strings. I've managed to get a app resource language string via a backdoor method. But I'm still having to rely on a string in my UI Test project.

Comment: You should be able by referencing the project that contains the AppResources files. if you want to force a specific language you can force a Culture change `AppResources.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr")`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is still relevant, assuming you have resx files for different localizations of the application and you want to access the German resx file what you need to do is to add the following attribute at the top of the test

```
[Test]
[SetUICulture("de-DE")]
public void MyTest()
{
// My test that read from resx file
}
```